# How rand() is calculated in PHP

Tags: php, random

I was just wondering how rand() really works in PHP, what's the math behind the scenes.

So when I call:

```
 rand(1,10);
```

What is PHP (or any there language) really doing to return a value?

Comment: PHP is open source, so you can see what they do, but this question is way too broad to be answered on SO.

Comment: Takes a `seed` value, runs it through a randomisation algorithm to get a new value, stores that value for the next seed; adjusts the value to an integer between 1 and 10, returns the value

Comment: View the source files of PHP, find this function... Happy days, you see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Random Number Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generators) also called RNG in short are actually generating [pseudorandom numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PseudorandomNumber.html), since it's impossible to actually generate a TRULY random number.

There are basically two parts of an RNG: **the seed**, and **the random number** chosen from that seed. When you seed the RNG, you are giving it an equivalent to a starting point. That starting point then has a bunch of numbers that are "inside" of it that the program chooses from. In PHP, you can use srand() to "shuffle" the seeds, so you almost always get a different answer. You can then use rand(min, max) to go into the seed and choose a number between the min and the max, inclusive. I don't have enough idea on how php chooses its seed to generate random number.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](http://lxr.php.net/) all the php functions with its c programming.
sorry for my english.